# render option twice in base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I got base.html.twig file inside i wanna render two controller 
Is that is possible ?

```
</head>
<body>
    {% block header %}{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\FrontController::front_header')) }}{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\FrontController::front_footer')) }}{% endblock %}
</body>
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

or what way is the best to handle something like that ?

becouse frontcontroller render anothe index.html.twig which will get some stuff to block content and i wanna have this block content between two another controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simply use [Twig include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) for your header and your footer?

Comment: yes exaclly and pass object through... works like charm :)